# Is there any property on apache camel seda queue to timeout a message if it stays in queue for too long?

Tags: apache-camel, apache-camel-3

I am using apache camel 2.18.0 version.

I am using seda queue with concurrent consumers option. What I am looking for is a way to control how long a message can remain in the queue itself.

For ex: Say a timeout configuration is set for 2 min, and once the message reached the queue, if it stays for more than 2 min, exception should be thrown.

In seda documentation this `timeout`  property is available

for ex:
`from("direct:start").to("seda:queue?timeout=120000"); // 2 minutes (in milliseconds)`

But this means message should reach the queue in 2min.

So, if there is no such property to cause timeout on message age in a queue, is it true that

1. Messages can stay in the queue until they are dequeued for processing?
2. If I want to control how long messages can stay in the queue, I may need to implement custom logic in application to periodically check and remove messages from the queue if they exceed a certain age?

Answer (score 1):

Ad 1) Yes they stay in the queue (forever)

Ad 2) Yes you need to write your own logic to remove messages from the
queue you dont want. You can also look at using a custom Queue implementation and provide a custom QueueFactory to the seda component.